# immutable collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i use a readonly collection to prevent users from altering my cached data, but the items themselves are ofcourse muatble.
Is there a way to prevent that behaviour?

Michel

Comment: return immutable objects, rather than mutable ones?

Comment: And, ehm, how can i make an item immutable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either make the cached items immutable themselves, or pass through *copies* of the objects.

Comment: how can i make a cached item immutable?

Comment: @Michel - You make immutable objects and cache them.

Answer (score 0):

you can set **private** constructor - so only inside items can create the instance.

Also , you can use the constructor to put readonly Values....

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have both an immutable and a mutable version of every business model object. I wrote an article on that here: http://rickyhelgesson.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/mutable-or-immutable-in-a-parallel-world/